# Q replication DB2 receiving error channel is distoreted

Tags: database, db2, replication, ibm-mq

I'm receiving an error ASN ASN2289W during Q replication with DB2 and websphere MQ 7.5. Any ideas on how to resolve it?

Comment: I'd start with looking up the warning code (it's not an error, as it has "W" at the end) in the manual.

Comment: And the warning should indicate a problem with codepages on the sender and receiver. Do they have the same or a compatible codepage?